# if statement python for column values

Tags: python, pandas, function, loops, if-statement

I am attempting to write the following logic in python:

if column A is '123' and column B is '456', then column c = 0

I've tried the following function, but returns an error:

```
 def testfunc(df):
     if df['columna'] == 123:
         if df['columnb'] ==456:
             df['columnc']=0

 return df
 testfunc()
```

error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: In input DataFrame exist column `columnc` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) and chain conditions with `&` for bitwise `AND`:

Solution if exist column `columnc`:

```
def testfunc(df):
    m1 = df['columna'] == 123
    m2 = df['columnb'] == 456
    df['columnc']= np.where(m1 & m2, 0, df['columnc'])
    return df
```

If not exist is necessary define both values like `0` and `10`:

```
def testfunc(df):
    m1 = df['columna'] == 123
    m2 = df['columnb'] == 456
    df['columnc']= np.where(m1 & m2, 0, 10)
    return df
```

**Sample**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
         'columna':[123,123,4,5],
         'columnb':[456,8,456,4],
         'columnc':[1,3,5,7],

})
print (df)
   columna  columnb  columnc
0      123      456        1
1      123        8        3
2        4      456        5
3        5        4        7

def testfunc(df):
    m1 = df['columna'] == 123
    m2 = df['columnb'] == 456
    df['columnc']= np.where(m1 & m2, 0, df['columnc'])
    return df

df1 = testfunc(df)
print (df1)
   columna  columnb  columnc
0      123      456        0
1      123        8        3
2        4      456        5
3        5        4        7
```

```
def testfunc(df):
    m1 = df['columna'] == 123
    m2 = df['columnb'] == 456
    df['columnc']= np.where(m1 & m2, 0, 10)
    return df

df1 = testfunc(df)
print (df1)
   columna  columnb  columnc
0      123      456        0
1      123        8       10
2        4      456       10
3        5        4       10
```